# Harvest Chosen jQuery plugin displaying previously selected and saved data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have added the Harvest Chosen plugin to my MVC3 application and I can load items from an entity. I am able to save the selected items back to another table through EF. My question is how do I display the previously saved items as Chosen (showing) in the Chosen Dropdown?

Should I use two Chosen Dropdowns? Dropdown A has the list from table A and Dropdown B has the saved items from table B. If so, then I guess I'd need to write code to ensure the Chosen Dropdown A no longer has the items that are now in Chosen Dropdown B? Or, can I use one Chosen Dropdown?

If I load table B to Chosen Dropdown B then I would expect the items to be in the Dropdown (not showing as selected). I've had a look around but I'm clearly missing something :(

Thanks All!

Comment: I've now got six items in Dropdown B. If I select items 1, 3 and then save. I have items 1-6 in Table A and items 1, 3 in table B. when I load my MVC3 page. I populate Dropdown A using a stored procedure to get all items except 1, 3. Dropdown B gets items 1, 3 as selected but but unchosen (not showing) All I need is the method to mark those items as chosen. Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, yes my jQuery skills do need some work!!
I was originally working with a collection of items and trying to do everything inline:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.ListBox("ParticipantsList", Model.Participants,
         new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Select Participants...", style = "width:350px;" })
</div>
```

"ParticipantsList" is my collection of id, value pairs. Model.Participants is the collection in my model and I had Script tags to reference the Chosen Plugin. I then had nowhere to set the option selected property for each item in my collection.

I changed the Chosen script:

```
       <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {jQuery(".chosen").data("ParticipantsList", "Select Frameworks...").chosen();});
       </script>
```

And then used a foreach loop to iterate the collection and set each items Selected property:

```
       <select class="chosen" multiple="true" style="width:400px;">
          @foreach(var item in Model.Friends)
             {
                <option selected="selected">@item.Text</option>
             }
       </select>
```

Hope that helps someone....